# Querying table is slow on website but fast via SSMS and they both have identical execution plans

Tags: sql-server, performance

According to SQL Server Profiler the following query takes 5-8 seconds to run from our website, however when I execute the same query in SQL Server Management Studio it returns immediately.

```
SELECT *
FROM MemberConversations
JOIN [User] AS Member ON MemberConversations.UserId = Member.UserId
LEFT JOIN Photo 
  ON Member.MainPhotoId = Photo.PhotoID 
 AND Photo.Discriminator = 'PublicPhoto'
LEFT JOIN Agency 
 ON Member.AgencyId = Agency.AgencyId
WHERE ConversationId = @conversationId
```

This query returns just two records and the MemberConversations table only has about 30 rows in it.

Having read a number of answers to similar questions on SO I've reviewed the execution plans for both the app and SSMS and they are identical:

[image]

If this is a deadlock or blocking issue, I would have thought that would also affect the query when it runs in SSMS. Each request that comes in starts a new transaction and then at the end of the request the transaction is committed. I'm using the *read committed* isolation level.

The website executes its database queries using Dapper.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you clear cache before running in SSMS?

Comment: @lad2025 I've tried clearing the cache and executing query as the same user and SSMS still returns immediately. If it helps, in the app I'm connecting using Windows Auth from a different machine (using mirrored local account).

Comment: Maybe this link could help you in solving this issue http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: @user2340218 from what I understand about parameter sniffing, it comes down to the execution plans being inefficient due to caching. I don't think this is the case here as the execution plans are identical.

Comment: Install `sp_whoisactive` and check both using app and SSMS

Comment: how you are connecting the database to youe application throught `Entity` ? or `Stored Procedures`

Comment: @Webruster I'm executing the query from the app using Dapper, a MicroORM

Comment: @ajbeaven `SO` also uses a `Dapper` here how they are solving the same problem(i.e. Query Execution Plan) [link](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/05/02/A+day+in+the+life+of+a+slow+page+at+Stack+Overflow)

Comment: @Webruster I don't think there's any issue with the execution plan - the SSMS query and Website query use the same one. I've added the execution plan for the website query to my question.